# select all children of an element

Tags: c#, xml, linq

The situation is following:

I have an `XDocument` containing XML structure like:

```
<report someatribute="smthin">
  <child></child>
  <othertypechild></othertypechild>

  ...etc...

  <Total>
    <Totalsum>totalsum</Totalsum>
    <Total1>sum1</Total1>
    <Total2>sum2</Total2>
    <Total3>sum3</Total3>
    <Total4>sum4</Total4>
    <Total5>sum5</Total5>
    <TimeFrom>...</TimeFrom>
    <Total6>...</Total6>        
  </Total>

  ....etc...

</report>
```

And I'd like to select all the child elements of `<Total>` element, that have name starting with "Total". Preferably using LINQ, but not necessarily.

EDITED: I forgot the condition with the name starting with "Total" (like "Total6", but also "TotalSuperUberCoolTagThatHasADifferentNameLength")

Comment: [What have you tried](http://bit.ly/16JPeVs)

Comment: i can't imagine you googled this and didn't get any help

Comment: ahh, now i know, i totally forgot about why i wanted to ask it. There's a catch. I'm going to edit the question accordingly.

Comment: You may check my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
XDocument xd = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
var query = xd.Root.Elements("Total")
    .Descendants()
    .Where(x=>x.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("Total"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = @"<report>
                <child></child>
                <othertypechild></othertypechild>
                <Total>
                    <Totalsum>totalsum</Totalsum>
                    <Total1>sum1</Total1>
                    <Total2>sum2</Total2>
                    <Total3>sum3</Total3>
                    <Total4>sum4</Total4>
                    <Total5>sum5</Total5>        
                </Total>
            </report>";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(s);

var total = doc.Descendants("Total");
var children = total.Descendants();
```

`children` will contain the elements you are looking for.

EDIT:  Here is a more complete sample, showing how to get values from the children, and get multiple `Total` elements.

```
string s = @"<report>
                <child></child>
                <othertypechild></othertypechild>
                <Total>
                    <Totalsum>totalsum1</Totalsum>
                    <Total1>sum1.1</Total1>
                    <Total2>sum2.1</Total2>
                    <Total3>sum3.1</Total3>
                    <Total4>sum4.1</Total4>
                    <Total5>sum5.1</Total5>        
                </Total>

                <Total>
                    <Totalsum>totalsum2</Totalsum>
                    <Total1>sum1.2</Total1>
                    <Total2>sum2.2</Total2>
                    <Total3>sum3.2</Total3>
                    <Total4>sum4.2</Total4>
                    <Total5>sum5.2</Total5>        
                </Total>
            </report>";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(s);

var totals = doc.Descendants("Total");

foreach (var total in totals)
{   
    var children = total.Descendants(); 
    children.Dump();

    var totalsum = children.Where(e => e.Name == "Totalsum").FirstOrDefault();
    var totalsunValue = totalsum != null ? totalsum.Value : null;
}
```